# Tournament scheduling issues

Tags: algorithm, tournament

Currently I'm working on a 1 day tournament scheduling application. Since, each year the number of participating teams is different, I want to automate the scheduling.

Teams are split in 2 groups. each group plays a single round robin tournament.
I managed to generate all the games to play, but I'm struggling with the planning.

additionally, the teams need to compete in 3 different sport disciplines, with each a dedicated field. (e.g. football field, volleybal field)

Given:
- games to play
- fields per sport + available timeslots per field (slots of +-15 minutes)

assumptions:
- timeslots are not limited
- 1 field per sport available
- schedule doesn't need to be balanced in 1st iteration

problems:
- the quality of my schedule is not that good. in fact, not all timeslots are fully filled, even if there is a solution. the 'density' of my schedule also depends on the order of games processed.

code snippet:

```
        //algo
        while (_games.Any())
        {
            gameToPlan = _games.Dequeue();

            var occupiedHomeTeam = GetTimeslotsOccupiedByTeam(gameToPlan.HomeTeam);
            var occupiedAwayTeam = GetTimeslotsOccupiedByTeam(gameToPlan.AwayTeam);
            var occupiedTeams = occupiedHomeTeam.Union(occupiedAwayTeam);

            var availableFields = fields.Where(f => f.AllowedSports.Contains(gameToPlan.Sport))
                                        .Where(f => f.Timeslots.Any(t => t.Game == null &&
                                                                        !t.Occupied &&
                                                                        !occupiedTeams.Any(oc => oc.Start == t.Start &&
                                                                                                 oc.End == t.End)));
            if (!availableFields.Any())
            {
                _games.Enqueue(gameToPlan);
                continue;
            }
            var field = availableFields.First();
            var timeSlots = field.Timeslots.Where(t => t.Game == null && 
                                               !t.Occupied && 
                                               !occupiedTeams.Any(oc => oc.Start == t.Start && 
                                                                        oc.End   == t.End))
                                    .OrderBy(t => t.Start);
             if (!timeSlots.Any())
             {
                _games.Enqueue(gameToPlan);
                continue;
            }   
            var ts = timeSlots.First();
            ts.Occupied = true;
            ts.Game = gameToPlan;
            gameToPlan.Timeslot = ts;
            gameToPlan.TimeslotId = ts.Id;
            _uow.Save();
        }
```

Can anyone give me an overview of approach, available algorithms,...?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your problem, this is clearly a discrete optimization problem. For tournament/timetable problems, you should think about using **constraint programming** solvers. You need to be familiar with linear/[integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) to do so. For example you can use [Choco solver](http://choco-solver.org/) which is in Java. Fun fact is that the last question on their [forum](http://choco-solver.org/node/239) is related to tournament scheduling.

Comment: thanks for your input! any idea of a decent .NET Constraint programming solver?

Comment: Not that I know. The two most used freely available are Choco (Java) and Gecode (C++), and the most un-free used is CP Optimizer (a free trial version is available). According to wiki, google-or accepts .NET, but I never use it. Finally, if you are interested in solutions that may not be optimal, you can have a look at LocalSolver.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at those items. Thanks for your information!

Comment: You're welcome. If it helps you,don't hesitate to upvote and/or valid the answer :)